# XMPP dialback; How to communicate between Receiving and Authoritative server?

Tags: authentication, xmpp, server

According to XEP-0220 the Authoritative-Server receives via a new connection `db:verify` and sends a go or no-go back to the Receiving-Server.

How can he send the `db:verify` to an other server without having a established connection?

According to the RFC a proper XMPP stream is initialized by `stream:stream` and `stream:features`. But then we are stuck in a loop cause he wants to authenticate again.

I am pretty sure I missed something here. I appreciate any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer and quote from jabber mailing list:](http://mail.jabber.org/pipermail/jdev/2015-February/090091.html)

> You have to distinguish between authenticated and unauthenticated
>   streams. You can, and in fact have to, exchange dialback elements over
>   unauthenticated streams. So there is no loop.

I missed the point that only `<message/>`, `<presence/>` and `<iq/>` require authentication.